# addEventListener not using its function

Tags: javascript, events, frontend

Essentially, whenever someone clicks the "createTextButton", the "currentTool" is switched to the function associated with that button. Then, when someone clicks on the drawing surface, the function assigned to the currentTool should be called by addEventListener, but it isn't.

Am I missing something here? Mozilla documentation says AddEventListener can receive a object or function as its 2nd parameter. In Node.JS, I use callbacks like this all the time. Is there something different here?

```
 var currentTool = null;

 var svg = document.getElementById("drawing-surface");

 var createTextButton = document.getElementById("createTextButton");

 createTextButton.addEventListener("mouseup", function(event) {
     currentTool = createText;
 });

 svg.addEventListener("mouseup", currentTool);

 function createText(event) {
     ...
 }
```

Comment: where did you define "createText"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're passing `null` to `svg.addEventListener`. The value given is the value of the variable *at the time the function is called*; if it is later changed, that won't affect anything.

To achieve what you want, you can wrap your event listener in another function:

```
svg.addEventListener("mouseup", function(event) {
  if(currentTool != null)
    currentTool(event);
});
```

This works because now we refer to the variable `currentTool` *each time the event happens* instead of only when `addEventListener` is called.